# Macbook is connected to wifi and tethering from iPhone. Which connection is it using?

Tags: iphone, wifi, macbook-pro, internet, tethering

When on wifi with my Macbook, sometimes I plug my phone in via USB and both connections say they are working.  How do I know which connection my Macbook is using?  Further, how do I force my Macbook to prefer the wifi connection?

[image]

I'm running Mountain Lion 10.8.4 on a Macbook Air Mid 2011, and iOS 6.0 on an iPhone 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preferred connection is shown at the top of your list.  This doesn't mean that the iPhone USB connection will never be used; but, it makes it less likely.

You can control which connection will get precedence with the gear icon at the bottom of the list window you showed, and select "Set Service Order".